# R loop - how to use it correctly?

Tags: php, r, for-loop, shiny

I am coming from PHP background and still trying to get my head around R.

For instance, I can easily loop an array in PHP and manipulate the data,

```
$array = [
  "site1"   => 9
  "site2"   => 10
  "site3"   => 18
  "site4"   => 28
]

foreach($array as $index => $id) {
   echo $id . '<br/>'; 
}
```

result,

```
9 
10 
18 
28
```

But in R, I have this data frame for instance,

```
    siteKey siteCode
1   site1   9
2   site2   10
3   site3   18
4   site4   28
```

loop,

```
for(i in 1:length(sites.df$siteKey)) {
    print(sites.df$siteCode)
}
```

result,

```
[1] "9"  "10" "18" "28"
[1] "9"  "10" "18" "28"
[1] "9"  "10" "18" "28"
[1] "9"  "10" "18" "28"
```

I thought it should be this result below?

```
"9"  
"10" 
"18" 
"28"
```

Any idea how I can use the R loop to get the result above that I need?

**EDIT:**

The query,

```
  # Prepare SQL query1.
  dataQuery <- "SELECT 
                *
            FROM speckdata AS s

            LEFT JOIN weatherunderground AS w 
            ON s.wid_timestamp = w.wid_timestamp

            LEFT JOIN nodes AS n 
            ON n.nid = s.nid
            AND n.datatype = 'speck'

            WHERE n.nid = 'SITE'
            "
```

Maybe better to loop this below?

```
  #
  # Data: site 1
  #

  # Match the pattern and replace it.
  data1Query <- sub("SITE", as.character(site1), data1Query)

  # Store the result in data1.
  data1 = dbGetQuery(DB, data1Query)

  #
  # Data: site 2
  #

  data2Query <- sub("SITE", as.character(site2), data2Query)

  # Store the result in data.
  data2 = dbGetQuery(DB, data2Query)

  #
  # Data: site 3
  #

  data3Query <- sub("SITE", as.character(site3), data3Query)

  # Store the result in data.
  data3 = dbGetQuery(DB, data3Query)

  #
  # Data: site 4
  #

  data4Query <- sub("SITE", as.character(site4), data4Query)

  # Store the result in data.
  data4 = dbGetQuery(DB, data4Query)
```

Then merge all the data,

```
      # Merge data sets.
      set.seed(1)
      dataList = list(data1, data2, data3, data4)
      allData = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), dataList)
```

Then plot the data,

```
           timePlot(
                allData,
                pollutant = c(species, condition), 
                avg.time = mean,
                lwd = 2,
                lty = 1,
                type = "site",
                group = TRUE,
                auto.text = FALSE
            )
```

Comment: A solution not requiring a loop. `writeLines(as.character(sites.df$siteCode))`

Comment: I agree with the other comments. If you goal is to print the values in the `siteCode` column, there is absolutely no reason to use a loop. In fact, you already use the appropriate code, i.e., `print(sites.df$siteCode)`. Why you felt the need to wrap this in a loop is unclear. If the goal isn't printing, you need to specify it in your question. However, there is a good chance that you still won't need a loop. Read [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: @Roland please see my edit above for the reason I want to loop it. I might have to repeat the same lines when I have more sites to be added. So I think it would be better off looping it.

Comment: Create a reproducible example for your broader question. Not just snippets of code. e.g. the values of `dataQuery`? Provide some numbers that we can try methods.

Comment: `lapply` was designed for this. Something like `lapply(sites.df$siteKey, function(x) {
  data1Query <- sub("DATE1", as.character(date_from), dataQuery);
  data1Query <- sub("DATE2", as.character(date_to), data1Query);
  sub("SITE", as.character(x), data1Query)
})`. (Not tested because there is no reproducible example.)

Comment: the `sub` usage could possibly be replaced with assignments. `data1Query <- sub("DATE1", as.character(date_from), dataQuery)` can turn into `data1Query$DATE1 <- as.character(dataQuery$data_from)`. But again, without specific examples, it's just speculation.

Comment: @plafort please see my edit 2 above. that is how I get the values for `dataQuery`. It is awful currently as I repeat same lines. I use Shiny framework btw.

Answer (score 2):

Add a call to [i] in your loop like so...

```
for(i in 1:length(sites.df$siteKey)) {
    print(sites.df$siteCode[i])
}
```

This way, each iteration will print the single instance at location [ i ].

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I just can't think of any real world situations where a for loop is the best method for printing column values to the screen. They can be referenced directly with `sites.df$siteCode` for data manipulation.

Comment: I don't think OP is going to be using this for any real-world purpose other than learning the construct of R for loops.

Comment: And the best lesson is to learn how R allows you to avoid it.

Comment: see my comment above and beneath the original post.

Comment: of course `writeLines(as.character(sites.df$siteCode))` this is what I will go for. but it should be `writeLines(as.character(sites.df$siteCode[i]))`.

Comment: @Elin seriously, I don't know what you are on about. If you have a better idea, please suggest. Note that this is not about PHP. thanks

Comment: @plafort please see the answer from dsifford.

Comment: You won't need the [i] using @plafort's method

Comment: I get this `9
10
18
28
9
10
18
28
9
10
18
28
9
10
18
28` instead of `9
10
18
28` without [i].

Comment: Are you placing it within the loop? Because you shouldn't be. Use that a la carte

Comment: you were not supposed to put my code inside of a for loop. Just enter it alone.

Comment: @plafort i need the loop as I need to loop other things as well.

Comment: [Vectorization in R: Why?](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html)

Comment: @plafort please see my edit above for the reason I want to loop it. I might have to repeat the same lines when I have more sites to be added. So I think it would be better off looping it.

Comment: @teelou read the first line of the question. He is thinking in PHP not in R.   In R loops are generally strongly discouraged because of vectorization and performance. There are some cases where they are needed but certainly not here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @dsifford is ok in base R. However, I recommend to have a look at the `dplyr` package early in the switchover from php, because it makes things much more transparent than the hopeless mess of `xapply` functions (apologies to all radical base-R-ers).

```
library(dplyr)
site.df = data.frame(siteKey = paste0("site",1:4), siteCode = runif(4,9,28))

site.df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  do(print(.$siteCode))
```

In itself this is not really easier, but if you have additional manipulations, it makes for a smoother ride.

Comment: One of the features of `*apply` functions is that they are more transparent than `for` loops - I'm not radical base-R. While I agree that `dplyr` is worth to look at, in this particular example I don't think it makes it any more transparent. Maybe you can include benchmark to present some potential advantage.

Comment: What are `radical base-R-ers` btw? How do you define them?

Comment: You can find radical base-R-ers in the comments section above: they define xapply as the gospel and for-loops as the devil. The truth is more complex, see dozens of comments from the earlier years of R. http://r-project.markmail.org/thread/o3vz2tlm2z22og27. I use a for-loop when speed does not matter, and the scoping rules and the non-idempotency of xapply (returns are list, have to use do.call(rbind..)) get in the way. `dplyr` is xapply the consistent way.

Comment: @jangorecki: Quite sure, this is slower, and when it matters, I check. When it does not matter, I drink a cup of coffee in the milliseconds wasted. Note, however, that I mentioned `dplyr/rowwise as a special case of a grouping operator which is useful if you do other things in the `%>%` chain. Not because of speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question as written is "R loop: How to use it correctly?"

You propose this code

```
for(i in 1:length(sites.df$siteKey)) {
    print(sites.df$siteCode)
}
```

This code would be an example of using an R loop correctly (if you insisted on it, even though it is discouraged).

What this code is saying is for each pass print out the "column" or complete list of values for $siteCode.  The loop is repeating that print request for each site, so you are getting the same complete list for each pass.

As suggested above by @dsifford changing it to

```
for(i in 1:length(sites.df$siteKey)) {
    print(sites.df$siteCode[i])
}
```

will mean that instead of printing the entire list it will print just the i*th* value from that list for each pass.

The new code you added has different issues, specifically you are repeating the same code over and over for each site. You might want to consider writing functions to replace the duplicate code and then feeding the functions the list of sites you are using. That is a case where a loop may possibly make sense (although it may not).  But that is all a side issue from your original question.